# Create a list of floats with only a specific decimal [0.0, 0.7, 1.0, 1.7, 2.0, 2.7, 3.0, 3.7, 4.0, 4.7, ...etc]

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am reading from an excel file and require the generation of a list to pull from where it has every integer in a range to the number read as well as a specific decimal between each integer.

For instance, if I read that I require 2.3 units of x, then I would like to generate a list in range 0 to 2.3 that has [0, 0.3, 1.0, 1.3, 2.0, 2.3].

I have thought about adding two lists together:

```
Units = 3.3
ListIntegers = list(range(math.ceil(Units)))
ListFloats = list(range())      # Here I would need to create the 0.3, 1.3, 2.3, and 3.3
FinalList = ListIntegers + ListFloats
 
FinalList.sort()      # This will put my list back in numerical order
```

1. How would I create that list of specific float values?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A one-liner:

```py
x = 2.3
a = sorted([i for i in range(int(x)+1)] + [(x - i) for i in range(int(x)+1)])
```

This creates a following list:

```
[0, 0.2999999999999998, 1, 1.2999999999999998, 2, 2.3]
```

This is due to floating-point operation precision. To solve this, you'd have to round numbers in the process (as you can see, even rounding to 10th decimal place gives the result you want)

```py
x = 2.3
a = sorted([i for i in range(int(x)+1)] + [round(x - i, 10) for i in range(int(x)+1)])
```

Result:

```
[0, 0.3, 1, 1.3, 2, 2.3]
```

Comment: @RyanWhite this answer is slow if you care about speed

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
import itertools
Units = 5.8
j = round(Units%1, 1)
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((i, i+j) for i in range(int(Units)+1)))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0.8, 1, 1.8, 2, 2.8, 3, 3.8, 4, 4.8, 5, 5.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?:

```py
import math

Units = 5.8
addition = float("0." + str(Units).split(".")[1])
intList = list(range(math.ceil(Units)))
finalList = intList + [x+addition for x in intList]
finalList.sort()
print(finalList)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0.8, 1, 1.8, 2, 2.8, 3, 3.8, 4, 4.8, 5, 5.8]
```

#### Edit

Per [funnydman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9926721/funnydman) and [Nin17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15456681/nin17) ... the `addition` part could be dirty. You could change to something like the below. The assumption is that `Units` will always be a float (have a decimal) because we are splitting it at that decimal to find the number of decimals points.

```py
import math

Units = 6.8923
addition =  Units%1
decimalLen = len(str(Units).split(".")[1]) # Find length of decimals past the decimal point for rounding purposes
intList = list(range(math.ceil(Units)))
finalList = intList + [x+round(addition, decimalLen) for x in intList]
finalList.sort()
print(finalList)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0.8923, 1, 1.8923, 2, 2.8923, 3, 3.8923, 4, 4.8923, 5, 5.8923, 6, 6.8923]
```

Comment: float("0." + str(Units).split(".")[1]) is a bit dirty

Comment: why not use ```addition = Units%1```?

Comment: @Nin17 5.1 % 1 => 0.09999999999999964

Comment: @funnydman idk do some rounding?

Comment: This is perfect! I ended using:
addition = round(Units - math.floor(Units), 1)

Comment: Yes, anyway better then magic string

Comment: @RyanWhite see my answer if you care about speed

Answer (score 0):

Surely not the best way, but this first comes to mind:

```
Units = 2.3
frac, _ = math.modf(Units)

result = []
curr = 0
for i in range(int(Units)*2+2):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        result.append(curr)
        curr += (1 - frac)
    else:
        result.append(curr)
        curr += frac
print(result)
```

Comment: why ```i in range(10)```?  OP says it should include Units: ```range(int(Units)*2+2)```

Answer (score 0):

To complete your snippet:

```
import math
Units = 3.3
ListIntegers = list(range(math.ceil(Units)))

decimal = round(Units - math.floor(Units), 1)
ListFloats = []
for integer in ListIntegers:
    ListFloats.append(integer + decimal)
FinalList = ListIntegers + ListFloats
FinalList.sort()
```

Comment: This answer is working for me, thank you! I was able to eliminate the for loop by using list comprehension
FinalList = ListIntegers + [x + decimal for x in ListIntegers]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your questions, I can say that

1. There are several algorithms to perform the same task. It all depends on what you fancy.
2. There's always space for improvements.

If I understand you correctly, the solution I came up with doesn't use if-elses, sorting nor list concatenation.

It generates a list with the double of size basing on the integer part of the `Unit` (except from 0 which doubles anyway). Uses only one math import `modf` and some operations, such as `//`, `**` and `%` and a list comprehension.

```py
from math import modf

Unit = 3.3
Decimal, Integer = modf(Unit) 
transform = lambda i, d: round(i**(i%2)//2 + (i//2+d)**(1-i%2),2)
a = [transform(i, Decimal) for i in range(-1, 2*int(Integer)+1)]

print(a)
```